# Poetry create new virtual environments after installing conda

Tags: python-poetry, miniconda

Here is the story of how I got poetry and miniconda messed up on my mac:

I cloned a project from the git hub, and PyCharm created a virtual environment (`venv`). I installed Peotry (not in `venv`) and used it to manage my packages. So far, so good. But after I installed miniconda (not in `venv`), when I run poetry install (with `venv` activated), it created a new virtual environment and installed all the packages there:

```
Virtualenv
Python:         3.12.2
Implementation: CPython
Path:           /Users/XinNiuAdmin/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/convert_neuralynx_to_nwb-w6GlhHFh-py3.12
Executable:     /Users/XinNiuAdmin/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/convert_neuralynx_to_nwb-w6GlhHFh-py3.12/bin/python
Valid:          True
```

The environment status is `(venv) (base)`. Could anyone tell me how I can reset poetry within my original virtual environment (venv)? Should I reinstall poetry within my virtual environment?

My workaround for this is to create a new environment with Conda and install the packages with Poetry. It seems everything works fine. It would be great if anyone could provide more insights on how Poetry and Conda conflict in this scenario.

Comment: Poetry only looks for a virtual environment in a directory named `.venv` (note the leading `.`). If that directory does not exist, and if you don't have a virtual environment activated, and if `virtualenvs.create` hasn't been set of false, then poetry will automatically create a virtual environment as you experienced. If you want to use a different virtual environment, you can simply activate it and poetry will use it automatically.

Comment: _"Should I reinstall poetry within my virtual environment?"_ No, as a rule you should never manually install poetry into a virtual environment. Poetry is itself a Python application that has its own dependencies, which you don't want to mix with your system/application dependencies. The recommend ways to install poetry (e.g. with pipx or the official installer) create an isolated virtual environment for poetry, which you don't directly interact with

Comment: Also do note [PyCharm has first-class support for poetry environments](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/poetry.html#poetry-env). If you plan to use poetry anyway, it may be simpler to directly specify your project interpreter as a poetry environment in PyCharm instead of creating a virtualenv environment and linking in poetry after the fact.

Comment: @Brian61354270, I am using two macbooks. On both of them, I created virtual environments with Pycharm. One has `.venv` and the other has `venv` in the project folder. Both works fine until I installed miniconda on the mac with `venv`. Maybe it will work with `.venv`.